# perform Regex on JSON data across each row and push into the MySQL table using NiFi

Tags: mysql, regex, apache, apache-nifi

I want to achieve the following use case:

I have a file as follows:

```
 enter code here
{"FirstName":6785,"Lastname":"Charles","Address":"1103 pioneer St"}
{"HouseName":67783,"Lastname":"Stevenson","Address":"Abel St"}
{"FoodName":7473,"Lastname":"luther","Address":"Half Moon Bay"}
```

si I want to add "NAME" and "Value" tag in the first column across each row so I can easily push all the FirstName, HouseName, and FoodName attributes under one column in MySQL named '**Name**' and its respective values under "Value" column in MySQL. for example I want the data to look like as following:

```
{NAME:"FirstName","Value":6785,"Lastname":"Charles","Address":"1103 pioneer St"}
{NAME:"HouseName","Value":67783,"Lastname":"Stevenson","Address":"Abel St"}
{NAME:"FoodName","Value":7473,"Lastname":"luther","Address":"Half Moon Bay"}
```

My table in MySQL is as follows:
**Name Value Lastname Address**

I am using the following flow:

**GetFile->SplitRecord->ConvertJsonToSQL ->PutSQL**

I want under the **NAME** column all the first column attribute names of each row(FirstName, HouseName, FoodName) and under **Value** column its respective values to be entered.

How can i achieve this use case in NiFi?
What Regex I should use in the ReplaceText to achieve this. Anny help is appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: @Toto I don't know which processor to use to achieve this. I am a newbie!  I think ReplaceText would help but then I don't know what Regex to use to achieve my use case. Any Help is much appreciated?

Comment: Sounds like a few lines of PHP code.  (I never heard of Nifi.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GetFile -> JoltTransformJson (or JoltTransformRecord) -> PutDatabaseRecord for this, which avoids the split and separate SQL generation/execution. Use the following spec in JoltTransformRecord:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Address": "[#2].Address",
        "Lastname": "[#2].Lastname",
        "*Name": {
          "$": "[#3].Name",
          "@": "[#3].Value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Notice I changed the output `NAME` column to `Name` to match your MySQL column name, it makes things easier on PutDatabaseRecord when the columns match the field names.